# PlaceAutocompleteFragment inside another fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm currently trying to display a PlaceAutocomplete search bar within PlacesFragment. Within PlacesFragment, I so far have:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutocompleteFragment  = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    placeAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(
            new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                    String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                            + place.getId() + "\n"
                            + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                            + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                            + place.getAttributions();
                    Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", placeDetailsStr);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", "An error occurred: " + status);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

My R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment is in the fragment_places.xml file as:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="109dp" />
```

However, I'm getting error

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener)'
>   on a null object reference".

Overall, I'm wondering if this a correct way to next a PlacesAutocompleteFragment within PlacesFragment, and if not, what should I do instead? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, Android Studio says that "'getFragmentManager()' is deprecated" and may return a NullPointerException, so how can I resolve this?

Comment: check if <fragment> is in Activity layout file? `<fragment> ` only works if its in activity layout file.

Comment: if you are using support library, use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Oh, moving <fragment> to the main activity layout file works! Now the search bar displays in all fragments even when I switch using the ViewPager, so how can I display it only from PlacesFragment?

Comment: do not use `<fragment>` this way. Instead replace it with `<FrameLayout>` and bind the fragment there like you have done it in first place. Only the id will differ and you'll have to make an object of PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="109dp" />
```

with

```
 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="109dp" />
```

Now in PlacesFragment onViewCreated method,

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_container, new PlaceAutocompleteFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(PlaceAutocompleteFragment.class.getName())
                    .commit();

}
```

in onAttachFragment method,

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
    if(childFragment instanceof PlaceAutocompleteFragment) {
        ((PlaceAutocompleteFragment)childFragment).setOnPlaceSelectedListener(
        new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                        + place.getId() + "\n"
                        + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                        + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                        + place.getAttributions();
                Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", placeDetailsStr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        }
);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like onPlaceSelected is never executed after I select a place though... any idea why?